# Function using list comprehension return only 1 element...?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am working on a function that takes a dictionary and has an email domain as the key and a list of people as the value.

Here is the code:

```
def email_list(domains):
    emails = []
    for users in domains.values():
      for user in users:
        emails.append(user)
        if user in domains["gmail.com"]:
            return [x + "@gmail.com" for x in emails]
        elif user in domains["yahoo.com"]:
            return [x + "@yahoo.com" for x in emails]
        elif user in domains["hotmail.com"]:
            return [x + "@hotmail.com" for x in emails]
        
    

print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

The output only returns:

```
['clark.kent@gmail.com']
```

Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix it??

Comment: Well, this function returns the first email it gets from the first user, what else do you expect?

Comment: When the return statement is encountered, you've only added one element to `emails`, so you get a result with only one element.

Comment: @MichaelO im not great with this stuff

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want

```
def email_list(domains):
    emails = []
    for users in domains.values():
        for user in users:
            if user in domains["gmail.com"]:
                emails.append(user + "@gmail.com")
            elif user in domains["yahoo.com"]:
                emails.append(user + "@yahoo.com")
            elif user in domains["hotmail.com"]:
                emails.append(user + "@hotmail.com")
        
    return emails

print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

Output:

```
['clark.kent@gmail.com', 'diana.prince@gmail.com', 'peter.parker@gmail.com', 'barbara.gordon@yahoo.com', 'jean.grey@yahoo.com', 'bruce.wayne@hotmail.com']
```

Comment: I edited the question. Even if the code is correct, improper indentation may cause an ```IndentationError``` or you would not get your expected output. @snoop

Comment: @snoop Sujay was right i already fixed it

Answer (score 2):

A `return` keyword marks then end of a function. In your code, as soon as the `return ...` statement is executed, the function ends. So, the rest of the code is of no use.

You can do a compact solution.
Here is what you can do:

```
def email_list(domains):
    emails = [[user+"@"+server  for user in users ] for server,users in domains.items()]
    return emails
```

Or more compact

```
def email_list(domains):
    return [[user+"@"+server  for user in users ] for server,users in domains.items()]
```

If you want all the email addresses in one list, you can do:

```
return [user+"@"+server for server,users in domains.items() for user in users]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through the code. when you encounter `emails.append(user)` for the first time, `user` was "clark.kent". Next, you encountered this block:

```py
        if user in domains["gmail.com"]:
            return [x + "@gmail.com" for x in emails]
```

At this point, `emails` is `['clark.kent']`, so your list comprehension results in `['clark.kent@gmail.com']` and you return that. The problem here is you return as soon as you see the first user.

Here is my approach:

```py
def email_list(domains):
    emails = [
        f"{user}@{domain}"
        for domain, users in domains.items()
        for user in users
    ]
    return emails

print(
    email_list(
        {
            "gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"],
            "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"],
            "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"],
        }
    )
)
```

Note that I did not need to test for domain at all. Instead, I simply use the domains (keys) to construct the email addresses. Also note that my list comprehension is double loop, but they are the same loop as your code.